# How can I add Memoji stickers to my emoji keyboard using Swift for an iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, emoji, memoji

I have just noticed that with iOS 13, WhatsApp gives the option of choosing Memoji (Apple's fun stickers) to the emoji option of the keyboard.  How can I implement this in my app?  My emoji keyboard does not have this feature by default.

Answer (score 2):

So it seems you just have to add the following to your textView/textField to enable the Memoji icons just left of the Emoji icons on the emoji keyboard:

```
textView.allowsEditingTextAttributes = true
```